# Entity Framework / SQL Server database locks

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, transactions, locking

I am having trouble to understand what locks my SQL Server database. I am accessing data from a SQL Server database via Entity Framework. While that web application is running, I am also checking data with SQL Server Management Studio.

Apparently, when I am trying to read different tables with right click "Select TOP n rows", I get a message

> Failed to retrieve data - Lock timeout period exceeded Error 1222).

This doesn't happen when I read the data manually via `Select * from ...` statement or at least I haven't noticed it yet. Is there any difference between those 2 approaches?

And more important how can I figure out what locks my database? I tried to do research but still not quite specifically understanding what to do. I tried using

```
DBCC opentran and than 
exec sp_who2 SPID
exec sp_lock SPID
```

which tells me there is an active transaction from Entity Framework but not which one exactly. I am using a few transactions in my application. But those are in my opinion on other tables than I am trying to access via Management Studio. Are those transactions locking up the whole database?

Appreciate any help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a great stored procedure who_isActive written by  Adam Machanic:

```
EXEC sp_WhoIsActive;
```

**In addition, this stored procedure shows an executable sql text.**

[The stored procedure can be downloaded here.](http://whoisactive.com)

e.g. query with `session_id = 75` is waiting of query with `session_id = 90`: 
[image]

This is a reason of your blocking.

`sp_who2` is great procedure too. E.g.:
[image]

Then you should decide whether this process should be killed:

```
KILL YourNumberOfSessionID
```